# Possible to detect variable assigning inside if conditions in PhpStorm?

Tags: php, debugging, phpstorm

Is it possible to detect variable assigning inside `if conditions` in **PhpStorm**?

```
if($gooditems = $items){
    // will result to always true
    // we don't want that
}
```

If not, is there a 3rd party method to detect variable assigning inside `if conditions` for `PHP` files?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

1. `Settings/Preferences | Editor | Inspections`
2. `PHP | Probable bugs`
3. `Assignment in condition`